# Script to find logs in directory

Tags: scripting, logs, for

I have my loop for:

```
for i in 1.34*
do
if [ -f $i/rela/*log ] ; then
echo $i >> /tmp/allog
else
echo $i >> /tmp/alnolog
fi
done
```

Is working well.
We have different version of releases in ascending order.
Often i need to create another file with all the version which don't have any log into the directory.
The problem is when i have to create this file with a lot of version to insert.

I'd like to create a script and ask the first release with which I have to start and the last one(the normal format for the release is 1.34.0.04).

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with simple shell patterns. E.g.

- `for i in 1.3[4-9]* 1.4[0-3]*` matches revisions `1.34 to`1.43`
- `for i in 1.34.0.0[4-9]* 1.34.0.[1-9]* 1.34.[1-2].0[1-5]*` matches revisions `1.34.0.04` to `1.34.2.05`

etc

Comment: I know, but my problem is create a loop for between the first release and the last one and take just what i need.

Comment: if your existing script works, then there are files of the form `1.34.0.03` in the current directory, and my modifications to your loop should accomplish what you wanted

Comment: I know what you mean, and i appreciate it.
But i like do a loop for between two variables:

 echo "Enter The Release Which You Have to start with : \c"
 read START
 echo "Enter The Release Which You Have to finish with : \c"
 read END

For i between START and END

Is it clearer now?

Comment: I think so... Let me add that you could read the patterns I described too (though I understand they are harder to type/think up then simple revision ranges)

Answer (score 0):

i've tried to create this script:

```
echo "Enter The Release Which You Have to start with : \c"
read START

echo "Enter The Release Which You Have to finish with : \c"
read END

cd ${RELDIR}
for i in $(eval echo "{$START..$END}")
do
if [ -f $i/rela/*log ] ; then
echo $i >> /tmp/allog
else
echo $i >> /tmp/alnolog
fi
done
```

But is not working because is stamp out just the two variables that i put.